# How to set a custom Header in Volley with Strings and Int

Tags: android, android-volley

I need to set the Headers of the Volley manually but i have to send strings and Int's.

I know that i should do something like this:

```
@Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> mHeaders = new HashMap<>();
                mHeaders.put("Name", "James");
                mHeaders.put("Country", "UK");
                return mHeaders;
            }
```

But i need to send some values of Int type.

```
@Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> mHeaders = new HashMap<>();
                mHeaders.put("Name", "James");
                mHeaders.put("Country", "UK");
                mHeaders.put("Age", 21);
                return mHeaders;
            }
```

But it is supposed to send a string, but the WebService needs a Int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a custom header and add it to the volley's request object. Here's an example

```
Map<String, String> mHeaders = new ArrayMap<String, String>();
mHeaders.put("StringType", Stringg);
mHeaders.put("IntType", integerr);
Request req = new Request(url, postBody, listener, errorListener) {
  public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
    return mHeaders;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that way but the Map<String, String> doesn't take Int's.

Comment: you dont put ints in headers they are strings. so put ur int as a string